# Surfaces and the boundary map of K-theory

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, kt.k-theory-and-homology

In the reduced K-theory we have the exact sequence of pair
$$ \tilde{K}(S(X/A)) \to \tilde{K}(SX) \to \tilde{K}(SA) \to \tilde{K}(X/A) \to \tilde{K}(X) \to \tilde{K}(A) $$
If choose $X$ to be a surface $\Sigma$ and $A$ to be its 1-skeleton, we end up with the sequence
$$ \tilde{K}(S^3) \to \tilde{K}(S\Sigma) \to \tilde{K}\left(\bigvee_{1\leq i \leq n} S^2\right) \to \tilde{K}(S^2) \to \tilde{K}(\Sigma) \to \tilde{K}\left(\bigvee_{1\leq i \leq n} S^1\right),$$
where $n$ is the number of closed curves in the 1-skeleton. Notice that I am using a cell decomposition with one 0-cell and one 2-cell and that the suspension of a bouquet of circles is a bouquet of spheres.

My problem is: since the first and the last term of that sequence are trivial, we only have to know what is the map in the middle to determine $K^{-1}(\Sigma)$ and $K(\Sigma)$, but how do I calculate this map?

I would prefer a more explicit answer.

Comment: The map $X \to X/A$ splits stably (in fact, after one suspension), so the middle map is zero.

Comment: @OscarRandal-Williams, you mean it splits in $K$-theory or for surfaces, right?

Comment: Are you asking about closed, orientable surfaces only?  In that case, the suspension is just a wedge of spheres (the suspension of the attaching map of the 2-cell, which is a product of commutators, becomes nullhomotopic after suspension - this is essentially due to the fact that $\pi_2$ is abelian).  So then, as Oscar says, the middle map splits.  In the non-orientable (closed) surface case, the attaching map involves a square, which becomes multiplication by 2 after suspension.  So the middle map is zero on n-1 factors and multiplication by 2 on the last factor.

Comment: I think Oscar explanation is extremely intuitive.